# Python class strange behaviour

Tags: python, class, aggregate

Have a class which supposed to create an object describing connection to remote Linux Server using paramiko.

```
class Oracle:
  def __init__(self):
  ...
  self.outfile = outfile
```

In this class I have 2 functions. One returns list of files:

```
def oratab(self):
  self.remote.send("cat /etc/oratab\n")
  ...
  return oralst
> [u'one', u'oneone', u'oneoneone']
```

Another one returns information from remote Server using the files list from oratab func:

```
def get_arcs(self, n):
        yield basestatus, sum(lst)
self.remote.send("exit\n")
time.sleep(1)
```

If I pass the value to get_arcs manually it works OK.
If I pass the call for oratab manually it works OK.
If I aggregate these 2 functions together:

```
for i, y in zip(instance.get_arcs(), instance.oratab()):
    print i, y
```

it returns the same result twice, even if it supposed to trim to the smallest one (both lists are 3-elements big) 
So if I call for any of those without another function call it looks nice, but if they are executed both in the same script the results are unexpected (even without zip())

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`get_arcs()` is a generator,  `oratab()` isn't. Try using

```
zip(list(instance.get_arcs()), instance.oratab())
```

Comment: I tried: __for a in (0, 1, 2): for i, y in zip(list(instance.get_arcs(a)), instance.oratab()): print i, y__ but it returned the first func iterable fine but second one has not been iterated at all: http://prntscr.com/et3dmg __orcl__ is the first element of oratab, whenever 2 others have not been called

Comment: I would rather not to iterate my oratab function as it needs a lot code refactoring

Answer (score 1):

Finally I got it:

```
for i, b in zip((0, 1, 2), instance.oratab()):
    print list(instance.get_arcs(i)), b
```

Comment: I must confess I'm a bit confused... my answer was actually not exactly right then... am I right? Is it possible to un-accept an answer?